# neovim plugin installed but not loaded

Tags: terminal, vi, neovim

I switch from VSCODE to neovim because I need free ram but neovim alone is not good as VSCODE not color no snippet, I installed plugins using vim plug but I have to trigger the plugins every time I use neovim by type "PlugInstall", when I quit neovim and back aging nothing there so I need to run "PlugInstall" again, how can I use the plugins without running "PlugInstall" here is my init.vim:

```
:set number
:set mouse=a
:set smarttap
:set autoindent
call plug#begin(has('nvim') ? stdpath('data') . '/plugged' : '~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plug 'junegunn/seoul256.vim'

" Declare the list of plugins.
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

" Visual Settings
Plug 'junegunn/goyo.vim'
Plug 'junegunn/limelight.vim'

" Color theme plugins
Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'






Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'tsony-tsonev/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim' " fuzzy find files
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'prettier/vim-prettier', { 'do': 'yarn install' }

cell plug#end()
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
syntax on

colorscheme onedark

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Visual Settings
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" For Goyo
let g:goyo_width=85

" For LimeLight
" Color name (:help cterm-colors) or ANSI code
let g:limelight_conceal_ctermfg = 'gray'
let g:limelight_conceal_ctermfg = 240
" Color name (:help gui-colors) or RGB color
let g:limelight_conceal_guifg = 'DarkGray'
let g:limelight_conceal_guifg = '#777777'
" highlight line
let g:limelight_bop = '^.*$'
" let g:limelight_eop = '\n'
let g:limelight_paragraph_span = 0

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" UI Settings
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Keep cursor in the middle of the page, useful for editing text
set so=999
" Turn limelight on by default
" autocmd VimEnter * Limelight
" Turn Goyo on by default
autocmd VimEnter * Goyo
" autocmd VimEnter * AirlineToggle
" In Goyo, if airline is turned on, do nto show scratch area
" autocmd! User GoyoEnter nested set eventignore=FocusGained
" autocmd! User GoyoLeave nested set eventignore=
```

I use MX-Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have "`cell plug#end()`", it should be `call plug#end()`.
Maybe that is the origin of the problem or did you copy it wrong?

Comment: OMG, I didn't notice that, LOL, thank you